# Xcode 10.1, macOS 10.13.6 & (iPhone) iOS 12.4

Tags: ios, xcode

I get the following error while building the App in my Macbook to run the app on my iPhone connected to Xcode studio.

**Could not locare device supported files** 
This iPhone 7 Plus (Model 1661, 1784, 1785, 1786) is running iOS 12.4 (16G77),

The versions of ma, xocode an iphone are as follows:

```
Xcode:10.1
macOS:10.13.6
iOS (iPhone): 12.4
```

I am not sure what am I missing here because this app runs well in Xcode simulators. Can someone please advise me the solution here?

Comment: Try updating Xcode to 10.3.

Comment: I see this message in AppStore in MackBook while want to update the Xcode: "Download an older version of Xcode?           The current version requires OS X 10.14.3 or later, but you can download the last compatible version." ?  What to do now ?